# Can I make a seperate HTML file for devices like mobile and tabs for my website?

Tags: css, web, mobile, media-queries, portfolio

I have made and published my website. I want to make it compatible with mobiles without using media queries as for that I have to change the whole code. Is it possible to have separate HTML files for mobiles? If yes, how to link that to desktop version?

Comment: you want to make a responsive website without using media query its a bad thinking and practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you filter it server side looking at user agent. But i cant say ive ever seen it done and it sounds like bad practice. A general rule of programming would be to avoid duplicating code. Or [dont repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as the principle is called.

If your mobile code is simple too different from the desktop code that you cant use media queries i would sugest just putting two sections on the page and using said media queries to show one and not the other.